# shall I use callback pattern in my custom function? node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

for example I have a function A that has to return some value

```
    function A(callback){
        //some computation
        var fakeData = 20;
        callback(null,fakeData)
    }
    function B(err,data){
      if(!err){
 console.log(data);
}

    }
A(B);
```

so as far as I know only I/O operations in node js runs asynchronously, so whats the difference if I right just this

```
   function A(){

            var fakeData = 20;
            return fakeData;
        }
        function B(data){

     console.log(data);

        }
      var data = A();
      B(data);
```

I mean both of them will run synchronously right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about these two functions then yes these two are identical
but this is not the use of callbacks as callbacks are used when you have a process which returns the result after some time or in the future like a database call or a rest api call or a file read/write operations for which we are not sure about when did they returns the result.

Answer (score 1):

The callback pattern is useful for a number of types of problems:

1. When your function uses asynchronous operations and you want to be able to notify the caller when the asynchronous operations are complete and perhaps pass a final result to the caller.
2. When your function wants the caller to supply some function that can be used in the computation of a result as in the callback that can be passed to `array.sort(callback)`.

You would generally NOT use a callback pattern to communicate the result of a synchronous operation because that just makes the code more complicated than just directly returning the result from the function.  So, if all your operations in `A()` are synchronous, then your second code option will be simpler to code and use.

Comment: so in this case I should use the second approach not the first right?

Comment: @user2715191 - If all your code in `A()` is synchronous, then just return the value from it and skip the callback.  It's simpler that way.  Yes, use the second approach.